# How to get the AR example running for Unity using Google's tango example

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

So I am starting out to do some projects in Tango using Unity. I cloned the examples from their github (https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity) and tried running their Experimental Augmented Reality example. So I figured out how to attach the scripts to their respective game modules.

However, everytime I try to run the program, in the ARScreen.cs script this line `m_textures = m_tangoApplication.GetVideoOverlayTextureYUV();` always returns null. So I combed through google's documentation to see what causes it to return null but I could not find anything on it. Is there anyone that successfully ran the Experimental Augmented Reality example that can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just verified that my Experimental Augmented Reality example works fine.

It looks like project tango has made a new release called "release-weyl" on sept 15th. I'm not sure if there is a mandatory firmware update for this new release.

I'm using previous version release-vonmises. Just try this release. It might just work.

Comment: Thanks Francois. I updated everything to the latest versions and pulled from the latest repository and now it works. I am not sure what the changes were, but man that was frustrating!